# How to add a common button in all activity?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout

Can we add a common button on all activity without add code in xml file.

we need to add some code in application class and button show in all activity of app.

Comment: Add code of button in a base class and implement that base class in every activty

Comment: Thanks for comment @RohitJakhar

Is this possible to show common button from application class.
we add some code in application class and button is visible in all activity.

Comment: IDK about this thing

Comment: use one base activity, add a button to the base activity and use fragments for the content, swap out the fragments as you need to

Answer (score 1):

First create a BaseActivity. Then add this code to onCreate of that:

```
class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nav_host)
        //the layout of baseActivity 
        LinearLayout layout =(LinearLayout) findViewById (R.id.base_activity_layout);

        //set the properties for button
        Button btnTag = new Button(this);
        btnTag.setLayoutParams(
            new LayoutParams (LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        ));
        btnTag.setText("Button");
        btnTag.setId(some_random_id);

        //add button to the layout
        layout.addView(btnTag);
    }
}
```

Then let other activities which you want to create being inherited from BaseActivity.

```
class FirstActivity : BaseActivity() {
//
//
}

class SecondActivity : BaseActivity() {
//
//
}

class ThirdActivity : BaseActivity() {
//
//
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. but I don't want to add code in all activity.
is this Possible?

Comment: By this solution you just add inheritance code to your activities. i mean you just need to change this code    "class FirstActivity : AppCompatActivity()"   to    "class FirstActivity :BaseActivity() "

Comment: Don't you want to change even this much?

Comment: No.

I need to access these from like
'class ApplicationClass:Application{
overrideonCreate(){
MyButtonClass().init()
}
}'

Answer (score 1):

class ButtonActivity: Activity() {
protected var btnCommon: Button

```
override fun onCreate(saved: Bundle?) {
    var layout = findViewById(R.id.layout) as ConstraintLayout
    btnCommon = Button(this)
    // set Button properties
    layout.addView(button)
}
```

}

How to use

```
class MyActivity: ButtonActivity() {
    onCreate() {
      this.btnCommon.setOnClickListener...... // now you can use.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer @KpStar. Is this possible to access without extend ButtonActivity.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is the best option for now.

Comment: it depends on what you want to do with this button. you can write your own custom view, add the logic inside that custom view and then just include that view in all of your xml where you need it. it won't be the same instance of the button, but the logic will do the same thing

Answer (score 1):

I saw in your comments that you specifically want to do this solely from your Application class. It is possible to add a callback that is called during lifecycle methods of every Activity, so you could add a button there. Every one of your Activities will have to have a root view in its layout of the same type and with the same ID for this to work.

```
class MyApplication: Application() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        
        registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(object: ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {
            override fun onActivityCreated(activity: Activity, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
                val rootView = activity.findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.myRootView)
                val layoutParams = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                ).apply {
                    // Set up the appropriate layout constraints here
                }
                val button = Button(/* ... */)
                rootView.addView(button, layoutParams)
            }

            override fun onActivityStarted(activity: Activity) = Unit

            override fun onActivityResumed(activity: Activity) = Unit

            override fun onActivityPaused(activity: Activity) = Unit

            override fun onActivityStopped(activity: Activity) = Unit

            override fun onActivitySaveInstanceState(activity: Activity, outState: Bundle) = Unit

            override fun onActivityDestroyed(activity: Activity) = Unit
        })
    }
    
}
```

Personally, I think this is messy, and I would do it in a top level function that you call from `onCreate()` in each of your Activities. Or better yet, use a single Activity in your app and use Fragments for the different screens.

Comment: Thanks for answer @Tenfour04.
Is this possible to show this button without add myRootView id in all activity xml file?